# Change of Copernicus citation style

Tags: citing, overleaf

I have just been given the task of writing a paper on Copernicus from a thesis. I am using this template in Overleaf: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/copernicus-publications-manuscript-preparation-template-for-latex-submissions/xmgtnrsvtptt
Which uses the bib style \bibliographystyle{copernicus}.

Now I add a citation which looks like this in the Bibl.bib file:

```
@article{barcelo2018chi,
  title={Chi-square analysis},
  author={Barcel{\'o}, Juan A},
  journal={The encyclopedia of archaeological sciences},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

I now insert it into the text so \cite{barcelo2018chi}

the output looks like this:

[image]

how can I make it look like this: (Barceló, 2018)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template already tells you how to produce different types of in-line citations:

```latex
%% LITERATURE CITATIONS
%%
%% command                        & example result
%% \citet{jones90}|               & Jones et al. (1990)
%% \citep{jones90}|               & (Jones et al., 1990)
%% \citep{jones90,jones93}|       & (Jones et al., 1990, 1993)
%% \citep[p.~32]{jones90}|        & (Jones et al., 1990, p.~32)
%% \citep[e.g.,][]{jones90}|      & (e.g., Jones et al., 1990)
%% \citep[e.g.,][p.~32]{jones90}| & (e.g., Jones et al., 1990, p.~32)
%% \citeauthor{jones90}|          & Jones et al.
%% \citeyear{jones90}|            & 1990
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the apalike or natbib styles instead.

The apalike package looks like what you are asking for but with square brackets instead - use with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. Or take a look at the different natbib styles here:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but Im not sure if copernicus let me use other bibliographystyles